# mysql access via mysql command works while via mysqldump does not for same user

Tags: mysql

I have a brandnew MySQL instance deployed and I'm attempting to port elements from my development environment to the production enviroment.

I created a user and granted it all the privileges.

This user can access the database from command line using:

```
mysql -u OPER -p MYDB
```

and create tables, insert, delete, truncate, etc.

Now, I use the command `mysqldump` to create a script that would generate all the tables (and insert some initial contents into some of them).

Now, I'm trying to inject this script into the new database using the command:

```
mysqldump -u OPER -h localhost -p MYDB < Tables_Only.sql
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'OPER'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect.
```

When querying for the granted privileges:

```
show grants for 'OPER'@'localhost' ;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for OPER@localhost                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'OPER'@'localhost'                  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `MYDB`.* TO 'OPER'@'localhost'    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the mysql server installed on local machine?

Comment: These commands were issued locally in the machine MySQL is installed.

Comment: why are you issuing this command `mysqldump -u OPER -h localhost -p MYDB < Tables_Only.sql` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my guess and part of my confusion seen in my comment above

> why are you issuing this command `mysqldump -u OPER -h localhost -p
>   MYDB < Tables_Only.sql` ?

`mysqldump` is for generating output. Use that script file later with the `mysql` command line tool.

What you have done is to ask `mysqldump` to start with the `-p` switch to prompt you for a password, which it gets input redirection from a `.sql` for !

So the passwords don't match, it wasn't your intent to begin it, and it bombs.

### User Management

```
-- The below 2 lines are just my catching up to the fact that you already have this user
CREATE USER 'OPER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'I_Forgot'; -- this user already exists for you
GRANT ALL ON MYDB.* TO 'OPER'@'localhost'; -- but I need to tweak my box to catch up to you

-- create a second user and set a password
CREATE USER 'OPER2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
GRANT ALL ON MYDB.* TO 'OPER2'@'localhost';

-- fix the first user
SET PASSWORD FOR 'OPER'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('HisPassword');

select user,host,password from mysql.user 
where user in ('OPER','OPER2');
+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user  | host      | password                                  |
+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| OPER2 | localhost | *EC760840CDAC6AF05321A7DDD05A84E18892AA97 |
| OPER  | localhost | *1175038192340E5DFFD6452E540B133E28B3E135 |
+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+

2 users, 2 different hashed password

show grants for 'OPER'@'localhost' ;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for OPER@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'OPER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*1175038192340E5DFFD6452E540B133E28B3E135' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'OPER'@'localhost'                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

show grants for 'OPER2'@'localhost' ;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for OPER2@localhost                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'OPER2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*EC760840CDAC6AF05321A7DDD05A84E18892AA97' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'OPER2'@'localhost'                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Test those two users at the command line.
```

### DB table import to a new db

```
create database MYDB;
GRANT ALL ON MYDB.* TO 'OPER'@'localhost';
use MYDB;

create table t1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    something varchar(20) not null
);
insert t1(something) values ('frog'),('chopstick');

create database MYDB2;
GRANT ALL ON MYDB2.* TO 'OPER'@'localhost';
```

Now at command line (note user your own path accordingly, not mine):

```
mysqldump -uOPER -p MYDB > c:\nate\out2.sql
mysql -uroot -p MYDB2 < c:\nate\out2.sql
```

That table with 2 rows is now in the `MYDB2` database.

Note: There is a time-wasting gotcha sometimes with having a space after the `-u` switch at the command line. That is why I jam the db user name right next to it like `-uOPER`.

Comment: Well @Drew, I sometimes wonder how far my stupidity can go... I'll try what you suggest later and let you know. Many thanks for the time being (much more will come when I try and it works!!!).

Comment: Well, I just checked and you were right reserving the right to be wrong. I'm using the command `mysql -u OPER -h localhost -p<password> MYDB < Tables_Only.sql` and still get the same error (**Access denied**). What puzzles me is the fact that the user has ALL privileges (see above).

Comment: ok so you can't even merely login with `mysql -uOPER -pOpenSesame`  then can you? To get to a `mysql >` prompt.  Ah nevermind, you said you could at the top of your question. Let me test some stuff. Pop by the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) room if you want.

Comment: Nope. I have some recollection of a "CONNECT" privilege, but cannot find any reference to it (or perhaps my recollection is wrong).

Comment: Well @Drew, it turns out that there was some sort of **duplication** of the user's definition (please don't ask me to elaborate). I dropped the user and created it again from scratch, and now everything appears to work as needed. I decided to accept your answer because it drove me to think in the right direction. Once again, many thanks for your assistance.